# Why isn't my mdDialog component's SCSS file being included?

Tags: webpack, sass, angular-material, angular-cli, mddialog

I have a fairly basic [Angular Material dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) component that delivers messaging to the user:

```
...

        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(
            UserMessagingDialog,
            {
                data: {
                    'messages': this.messagesToShow,
                    'messageColors': this.messageColors,
                    'messageIcons': this.messageIcons
                },
                hasBackdrop: false,
                panelClass: 'messaging-panel'
            }
        );

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            // angular.element('messaging .messaging-icon').removeClass('rotate-cw tinted');
        });
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'user-messaging-dialog',
    templateUrl: './user-messaging.dialog.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user-messaging.component.scss']
})
export class UserMessagingDialog {
    constructor(
        @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA)

        public data: any,
        public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<UserMessagingDialog>
    ) { }
}
```

I'm trying to style the interior toolbars, so I've included the parent component's SCSS file, as seen above. However, it's not being applied. Build is via Webpack/Angular-CLI.

The SCSS file contains plain CSS, and is included properly in the component that calls the dialog using the same path:

```
.messaging-panel .message-text {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    white-space: normal;
}
/* ... plus about 80 more lines */
```

I've also tried breaking the dialog styles into their own file and directly injecting styles via `styles` on the component.

Does a dialog accept a CSS file, and if so, why isn't it working for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Component styles normally apply only to the HTML in the component's
>   own template.
>
> Use the /deep/ selector to force a style down through the child
>   component tree into all the child component views. The /deep/ selector
>   works to any depth of nested components, and it applies to both the
>   view children and content children of the component.

so to target all of its child elements in the DOM from host we need to use,

```
  :host /deep/ <selector>{}
```

Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BtEXqdJSD0TRbYqdfiKf?p=preview).

Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deep).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the stylesheet was loading, but the styles were being scoped with attribute selectors in a way that broke my descendant selectors.

For instance, `.messaging-panel .message-text` would become `.messaging-panel[some_other_attr_id] .message-text[some_attr_id]`. The problem is that the parent selector has a different scoping attribute, which breaks the style rule.

My solution was to remove the parent selectors in those cases.

UPDATE: Madhu Ranjan provided a more appropriate [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45042765/1264804).